# how to break chain with yield_self

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to break yield_self (then) chain in ruby?

```
"a".then { |str| <break> if break_condition }.then { |str| str << "b" } # => I need "a"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I don't think that you can "break" the chain without raising an exception but</s> you can pass a tagged value from the first block to the second one:

```rb
"a".
    then { |str| [str, !break_condition] }.
    then { |str,do_it| do_it ? str << "b" : str }
```

---

**edit:** An other form that might be easier to work with:

```rb
"a".
    then { |str| break [str,true] if break_condition; str }.
    then { |str,broken| break str if broken; str << "b" }
```

Comment: it is exactly what I am looking for. I don't like interruption like break, raise, throw.  I needed something like railway programming https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

Answer (score 6):

You could move the whole code into another method and "break" the chain with a simple `return`:

```
def foo
  "a".then { |str| return str if break_condition ; str }
     .then { |str| str << "b" }
end
```

You could utilize [`catch`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-catch) and [`throw`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-throw):

```
catch do |brk|
  "a".then { |str| throw(brk, str) if break_condition ; str }
     .then { |str| str << "b" }
end
```

Alternatively, you could not use `then` in the first place:

```
str = "a"
str << "b" unless break_condition
```

Comment: I vote for the `catch`/`throw` because it doesn't require the complete refactoring of OP's (complex?) existing code.

Answer (score 2):

This might be silly, but since you can't `break` or `return`, I guess `raise` should do it:

```rb
def broken break_condition
  begin
    "a"
      .then { |str| break_condition ? raise(str) : str }
      .then { |str| str << "b" }
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    str = e.message
  end
end

>> broken true
=> "a"
>> broken false
=> "ab"
```

One liner works too:

```
>> "a".then { |str| true ? raise(str) : str }.then { |str| str << "b" } rescue $!.message
=> "a"
>> "a".then { |str| false ? raise(str) : str }.then { |str| str << "b" } rescue $!.message
=> "ab"
```

Comment: You most certainly can `return`, though (if that chain is in its own method)

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your chain with using just one `then` like this

```rb
result =
  "a".then do |str|
    next str if break_condition
    str << "b"
  end
```

or

```rb
result =
  "a".then do |str|
    break str if break_condition
    str << "b"
  end
```